# Integration of two different functions

Tags: integration

I'm stuck with a problem, can anyone help? What if we integrate $$\int \frac{x\cdot dx}{mg+kx}$$? Actually I faced this in physics. But I need this basic knowledge of integration. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: Add and subtract $mg/k$ to the numerator.  Then you'll be integrating a constant and $1/x$.

Comment: No, as I am a student of class 11 in india, and here integration is in class 12, so I have not gone in depth. But I came across this in of physics, and while solving a problem, I'm stuck in this integration. No, I'm not familiar with it. Can you please give me a crystal clear explanation of it?

Comment: @Michael can you please post your explanation in answer box elaborately?

Comment: What are the "two different functions" in the title?

Comment: If you haven't seen any integration before, this might not be the best place to learn integration.  If you're just interested in the answer, Wolfram alpha is your best option.

Comment: $$\int \frac{x\cdot dx}{mg+kx}=\frac{x}{k} \ln{|mg+kx|}-\frac{1}{k}\int \ln|mg+kx|dx=$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider
$$
\int\frac{x}{mg+kx}dx.
$$
Add and subtract $mg/k$ to the numerator to get:
$$
\int\frac{x+mg/k-mg/k}{mg+kx}dx=\int\frac{x+mg/k}{mg+kx}dx-\int\frac{mg/k}{mg+kx}dx.
$$
Factoring out $\frac{1}{k}$ in the first integral and using a $u$-substitution of $u=mg+kx$ (so $du=kdx$) on the second integral, we get
$$
=\frac{1}{k}\int\frac{kx+mg}{mg+kx}dx-\frac{1}{k^2}\int\frac{mg}{u}du=\frac{1}{k}x-\frac{mg}{k^2}\ln|u|=\frac{x}{k}-\frac{mg}{k^2}\ln|mg+xk|+C.
$$

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: but on second integral,  du=k.dx. So how does mg/k.dx become mg.du?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I made an error.  One has $dx=\frac{du}{k}$, so the second integral has a coefficient of $\frac{1}{k^2}$ after $u$-substitution.  The post has been corrected.

Comment: Yes, that sounds OK. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Let $u:=mg+kx \implies x= \frac{u-mg}{k}$ *and* $du=k\,dx$ then $$\int\frac{x\cdot dx}{mg+kx}=\int\frac{\frac{u-mg}{k}\cdot \frac{du}{k}}{u}=\frac{1}{k^2}\int\frac{u-mg}{u}\,du=\frac{1}{k^2}\int 1-\frac{mg}{u}\,du=\frac{1}{k^2}[u-mg\ln(u)]+C,$$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Substituting $u=mg+kx$ back into the result above yields the answer, $$\frac{1}{k^2}[mg+kx-mg\ln(mg+kx)]+C=\frac{mg}{k^2}(1-\ln(mg+kx))+\frac{x}{k}+C$$ as desired.